# Responsive "Media" in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I wrote this code:

```
      <div class="media text-xs-left">
        <div class="media-left media-middle">
          <p class="lead">
            <img src="default.jpg">
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
          <p class="lead">
            <h6>here text</h6>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

And everything is good when I open my site in full window but when I resize window to see how will it look on mobile phones, media object are not responsive. I want to display text under picture on devices with small screen. Please help me how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Add flexbox utility classes to the media object:

```
<div class="media d-flex flex-column">
```

You can also adjust the order of certain elements within the media object by adding `class="order-1"` and `class="order-2"` to the media body and media image.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/flex/

I also center-aligned the content at a specific break-point:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    .media-body {
        padding-top: 1em;
        text-align: center !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
    }

    .media img {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-width : 768px){

}
```

Change your css inside of that tag, for example:

```
@media screen and (max-width : 768px){
    .lead{
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
    display: block !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 is in Alpha version yet and according to the official website

```
Not yet available, but hopefully soon!
```

see http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/

and as for your problem please refer to the grid system of bootstrap, it is well explained in their website http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

you must do something like this in your code

```
<div class="container-fluid">     
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs col-xm">
      <div class="media text-xs-left">       
        <div class="media-left media-middle">              
          <p class="lead">                
            <img src="default.jpg">              
          </p>            
        </div>            
        <div class="media-body">              
          <p class="lead">                
            <h6>here text</h6>              
          </p>            
        </div>          
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

put in your code `.container-fluid` div and add `div.row` and `div.col-xs` or `div.col-sm` next. This classes are examples that are responsible for better response of your layout in different screen sizes.

Comment: Your code looks good but image is still near text on small screen sizes. For example on iPhone 5s, image occupies most of space and there is too small space to comfortable text reading.

Comment: I think you should use `.image-responsive` class on image, and adjust css `max-width` and `max-height` like this `<img src="default.jpg" class="image-responsive" style="max-width:100%">`also see this http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_img-responsive&stacked=h. You not limited to wrap the `<img>`also with div

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Navbar</title>
  <style>
    @media screen and (max-width:768px){
      h6{
        font-size: 20px;
      }  
    }
    body{
      padding:10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="row"> 
<div class="col-xs-12">   <img style="width:180px;height:90px" src="https://www.google.co.in/images/nav_logo242.png"> </div>
         
       
   <div class="col-xs-12">    <h6>here texthere texthere texthere texthere texthere texthere texthere texthere texthere texthere texthere texthere texthere texthere texthere texthere texthere texthere texthere texthere texthere texthere texthere texthere texthere texthere text</h6> </div>
  </div>        
</body>
</html>
```

Whenever u are making any device responsive web-page, start from making a mobile device, then go on for larger devices. This is the best and easiest way to do it.So,here i made as u had said for mobile devices.